# Android call recording feature

Tags: android, recording, phone-call

As discussed in other posts, most Android devices don't support recording calls.
Recording AudioSource.VOICE_CALL does though work fine on my Samsung Galaxy S2.

Does anyone know if supporting this is Google's new trend, or it's just a feature specific to SGS2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Google is moving towards recording voice calls. In fact, I think they are probably working on ways not to allow this due to large security issues. Speaking of which, some recent [news](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2011/080111-android-trojan.html) that happened a few days ago reports of such security flaws. I don't think that using `AudioSource.VOICE_CALL` was meant to be used in this way. Hope this answered your question.

**Update:** News link from 2011 is unfortunately broken now. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's kind of spilling the baby with the bath water. Imagine keyboards were forbidden because some bad people write key loggers...

Comment: And anyway, how was AuioSource.VOICE_CALL meant to be used if not this way? I think it's its main reason to exist..

Comment: Alright, well I apologize for if my answer doesn't point you in the right direction. I just wanted to provide some evidence that Google may not necessarily be moving towards a trend of allowing apps to recording phone calls. On another note, it may just be as you mentioned, not all devices support those features.

Comment: news link is broken.

Comment: My apologies, that was from 2011, probably shouldn't have been referencing links like that anyway since they can get broken.

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't have any control over this (unless they start mandating that devices must / mustn't support voice call recording in their Compatibility Definition Document).
They have provided a way for applications to request the voice call audio by adding the `VOICE_CALL` `AudioSource`, but the actual implementation of this feature is platform-specific and is handled by the platform vendors and OEMs.

It may, however, be the case that you see more *platforms* having support for this feature now than you did back in 2011 (or 2010, since it takes a while for new platforms to appear on the market in consumer products).
I've worked with about half a dozen different mobile platforms over the last couple of years. Of these, every single one has had support for recording voice calls, although on two of them the software support was unfinished.

TL;DR: No, it's not an SG2-specific feature, but it's also not universally supported. And it doesn't really have anything to do with Google.

Comment: I have an SGS2. With Samsung original ROMs 2.3.3 and 4.0.3 it worked fine. With Samsung original ROM 4.1.2 it doesn't work. Obviously not a hardware issue.

Comment: I've been working with Jellybean for the last 8 months or so (in fact, voice call recording is one of the features handled by my team), and I can tell you that there are no changes from Google that would break voice call recording support. If someone broke it, it was probably Samsung or whoever delivers the platform for the SGS2. Due to the sheer size of Android and all the underlying platform code it's inevitable that bugs creep in between releases, and some will remain undetected or unfixed for one reason or another.

Comment: Strange, I tried the Nexus 4.2.2 ROM, which is practically clean Google code, and yet recording didn't work. On my current ROM, there's a built in call recorder, so I'm sure it's possible to get the line in. But VOICE_CALL doesn't work for me.